# log4j doesn't log message with unicode characters

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I have a Log4j logger.
When I call it with the string like this:

```
logger.info("test case")
```

It works fine and logs the message.

But when I call it with the Unicode characters:

```
logger.info("test case €")
```

It logs nothing, and it looks like it's just not called.

So this code will print only one log message - "test case":

```
 logger.info("test case")
 logger.info("test case €")
```

I've read that logger uses system charset if it's not explicitly set, and it's UTF-8.
I need to log this "€" sign and message with it.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting the encoding?
Also, make sure the platform you're reading them from is unicode enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log4j does not print UTF-16 characters by default, you will have to apply explicit encoding.
something like `log4j.appender.logfile.encoding=UTF-16` in your *.properties will do the trick.